# sql creating a trigger on update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

1. `members` and it has a nullable column called `blocked`,`ID` and `primaryPhone`.
2. `blockedinfo` it has 2 columns  `info` and `type`.
3. `phoneNumbers` it has `ID`, `prefix`, `phoneNumber`, `memberID`

I'm trying to create a trigger on the `members` table to insert the user primary phone number to the `blockedinfo` table when I set the blocked field in the members table. And remove it from the `blockedinfo` when I set the `blocked` field to `NULL`

```
CREATE TRIGGER `members.before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON  `members` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF( NEW.`blocked` IS NOT NULL ) THEN 
INSERT INTO  `blockedinfo` ( phone,  'userPhoneNumberValue') 
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) AS  'phone' 
FROM  `phonenumbers` 
WHERE  `ID` = NEW.`primaryPhone` 
AND  `memberID` = NEW.`ID` 
LIMIT 1 ;
ELSE 
DELETE FROM  `blockedinfo` WHERE  `info` IN (
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) 
FROM  `phonenumbers` 
WHERE  `ID` = NEW.`primaryPhone` 
AND  `memberID` = NEW.`ID`);
END IF ;

END ;
```

I get this error when trying to build the trigger

The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `members.before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `members` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN `MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''phoneNumberValue') SELECT CONCAT(`prefix`,`phoneNumber` ) AS 'phone' at line 4

Comment: Don't describe your tables. Edit your question, and post the SQL DDL instead. And the string literal that's in the error message ('phoneNumberValue') isn't in your trigger. Copy and paste what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, in this part

```
INSERT INTO  `blockedinfo` ( phone,  'userPhoneNumberValue') 
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) AS  'phone' 
FROM  `phonenumbers`
```

you provide a string literal, "userPhoneNumberValue", where you *should* provide the column name in "blockedinfo". Name the columns you're targeting here.

```
INSERT INTO `blockedinfo` (info, type)
```

In this part

```
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) AS  'phone'
```

you're providing one value. You need to provide two. I'm guessing that you need something more like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`prefix`, `phoneNumber`) AS phone, 'userPhoneNumberValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  `blockedinfo` ( phone,  `phoneNumber`) 
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) AS  `phone`
```

Here you try to insert 2 values but your select return just 1

try:

```
INSERT INTO  `blockedinfo` ( phone,  `phoneNumber`) 
SELECT CONCAT(  `prefix` ,  `phoneNumber` ) AS  `phone`, `phoneNumber`
FROM  `phonenumbers` 
WHERE  `ID` = NEW.`primaryPhone` 
AND  `memberID` = NEW.`ID` 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: I am actually trying to insert 1 value phone. the second one is a static string but when I use these quotes 'phoneNumber' I get an error when creating the trigger